expo-camera not recording video for Android
I'm using Expo Go version 51 to run my react-native application version 0.74.5. The goal is simple, it's to record a short 5-second video and display the log on the screen if successful. The expo-camera library version 15.0.16 used for this works very well for iOS, but on Android the video is not recorded, no error occurs, only the expo-camera library function, recordAsync, does not return anything. The problem is not with the camera usage permissions, all of them were assigned correctly. And I believe that the audio and microphone usage permissions are also not necessary since I set mute={true} inside my component.
Dry the takeVideo function:
const takeVideo = async () =>{
    setButtonVisible(false); // Oculta o botão imediatamente ao clicar
    const cameraInstance = cameraRef.current;
  
    if (cameraInstance) {
      try {
        console.log('Trying to record video...');
        const video = await cameraInstance.recordAsync({
          maxDuration: 5
        });
        console.log(video);
        if (video?.uri) {
          const videoUri = video.uri;
          setCapturedVideo(videoUri);
          setMessage('Image captured successfully!');
          setIsError(false);
        } else {
          setMessage('Error capturing image!');
          setIsError(true);
          console.log('Failed to record video.');
        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to record video:', error);
        setMessage(''Error capturing image!');
        setIsError(true);
      } finally {
        cameraInstance.stopRecording();
        setCameraVisible(false);
      }
    } else {
      setMessage('Error when trying to open the camera');
      setIsError(true);
      console.error('Camera reference not found.');
    }
  }

Here is the CameraView component:
<CameraView ref={cameraRef} style={styles.camera} facing='front' mode='video' mute={true} videoQuality='720p'>

              <View style={styles.ovalContainer}>
                <View style={styles.oval}></View>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                {buttonVisible && ( // Só exibe o botão se 'buttonVisible' for true
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={takeVideo}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Iniciar</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
              </View>
            </CameraView>

In this case the message displayed by the log running on Android is 'Trying to record video...' and it does not receive a response from recordAsync . I expect a response from the recordAsync function so I can view the 'console.log(video)'.
